# How to move an application from another desktop to the current one when using Windows' virtual desktop?

Tags: windows-10, virtual-desktop

I am using Windows' virtual desktop.

Let's say I have two virtual desktops A and B. First, I open an application via a shortcut icon at the right of the startup bar on desktop A, and then switch to desktop B. I again try to open the same application by clicking the shortcut. At this moment, I am switched from desktop B back to A since the application is currently opened at A, while what I want is to make the application window moved from desktop A to B.

Is there any method that makes this possible?

Noted that the application mentioned above is Slack, which allows only single instance at once. For Google Chrome and many other applications, multiple instances are allowed and in these cases, there are no problem switching between different desktops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Virtual Desktop is not that sophisticated. The only thing you can do is move the application manually the way it was designed. Go to the virtual switcher and drag the application to the other desktop to move it.

Comment: Sad answer but thanks!